# Ubuntu 12.10 working very slow

Tags: 12.10

My computer is working very slow after installing Ubuntu 12.10 Final.

Before I used to have Ubuntu 11.10 and it is working very fine for me, but after installing Ubuntu 12.10 it makes me very angry, working very very slow.

My Computer Configuration:

1. Pentium 4 3.4 GHz Processor
2. 1GB DDR2 RAM
3. 250GB HDD

Comment: Old hardware + little ram + unity + new linux version, more buggy than the older one, and you have the slowness.

Comment: It could just be that 12.10 is putting more of a strain on your older hardware than 12.04 was. If you're not too attached to any new features/fixes in 12.10, then it might be worth reinstalling 12.04 if that worked for you.

Comment: I have a similar machine. 1 GB RAM is too small - upgrade to at least 2 GB or more. You'll notice a considerable boost in performance.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Ubuntu 12.04 LTS release to see if that works ok on your system ?  12.10 is an incremental build but if you want 5 years support and stability then stick with 12.04...

Note: To speed up your desktop you could install the propriatary driver if you are using Nvidia or Ati graphics which would help...

Answer (score 0):

> Quoting myself from this question [Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit Slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235791/ubuntu-12-10-64-bit-slow/417892#417892)

Unity is **SLOW** and **INEFFICIENT** Get lxde it's **FAST** and **EFFICIENT**

*This is how you install it*

## Terminal way

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `sudo apt-get install lubuntu` for the full package and for the lighter one withut the applications type `sudo apt-get install lxde`
3. Type your password (You wont see anything typed for security reasons)
4. Wait for it to download and install
5. Logout/Restart laptop then on the login screen click the ubuntu icon on the password box
6. click lxde or lubuntu

## GUI way

1. Go to the ubuntu software center
2. Search for lxde or lubuntu
3. Install it
4. Logout/Restart laptop then on the login screen click the ubuntu icon on the password box
5. click lxde or lubuntu

enjoy your new desktop.